# Run same function on every component

Tags: angular

There is a piece of code I need to run on every angular2 component at the constructor.

I dont like the idea of copy-pasting that code on every component. Is there a way to write it down somewhere and call it from every .TS?

Thanks!

Comment: you can create a helper class with the static method and call that method on every component. `export class Helper { static thatMethod() {}}`

Comment: Depending on the situation either make a common service to handle the common code or make a base class that all your components extend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

generate a service typing "ng generate service" in the terminal. then include your functions then import your service and use dependency injection. then you can use your functions everywhere you import it.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class YourService {


  constructor() { }

  // your functions

  }
```

use in other components

```
//import your service here
import { YourService } from '../your.service';

export class YourComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private yourService: YourService) { }



  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  //your function calls
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use service!

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedService {

    somethingToDo() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and in component like

```
constructor(
    private shared: SharedService
) { 
  // here or in ngOnInit
  shared.somethingToDo()
}
```

Comment: Hi Dmitriy! So the injectable should be on a specific TS file? Im kinda new on Angular and I dont get your example. Thanks mate.

Comment: Short answer - `Injectable` tells Angular where this service should be injected in. Its a part of Angular [DependencyInjection](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection). `root` tells Angular that this service should be injected with root injector (basically top layer). Services can be also provided within specific module, but that`s a lot of talking for a comment. There are plenty of explanations in web.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I misunderstood your question, but I would use a `service.ts` class for this.

service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class ServiceClass {
   someFuntion(){
       //put your code here
   }
}
```

otherFile.ts

```
constructor(
        private serviceClass: ServiceClass
    ) {
        this.serviceClass.someFunction();
    }
```

I'm quite new to angular, so there may well be an easier way for this.

### Edit

The other answer says pretty much the same.